# Receiving 404 when configuring WCF with HTTPS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, https

I have an .NET 4.5 site deployed that has a MVC part and a WCF part. The WCF is hosted inside IIS and it is a subapp/subsite of the MVC application.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get HTTPS to work when MVC calls WCF. HTTP works, but as soon as I add HTTPS configuration, it stops working.

Here are my configurations:
MVC:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IApplicationContract" >
                <security mode="Transport">  
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>  
                </security>             
             </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>        
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://mysiteaddress.com/wcf/MyService.svc/Application" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IApplicationContract" 
            contract="MyServiceReference.IApplicationContract" name="BasicHttpBinding_IApplicationContract" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

WCF:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpStreaming" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="Streamed">         
            <security mode="Transport">  
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>  
            </security>             
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>     
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <endpoint address="Application" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Contract.IApplicationContract" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServicebehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am getting an error that says:

"EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://mysiteaddress.com/wcf/MyService.svc/Application that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.]"

If, in MVC configurations, I change the endpoint address to "http://localhost/wcf/MyService.svc/Application" and remove the  element and then, in WCF, I remove the , in other words, remove all HTTPS settings, everything works fine!.

With the HTTPs settings, I was getting a security misconfiguration error before, which disappeared after I added code to enable TLS 1.2, as it is not enabled by default on .NET 4.5.

Does anyone know what I am missing here?
IIS has a binding and MVC site is working perfectly in HTTPs, just when it tries to call WCF, an error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, for WCF configuration, in HTTP, if you do specify more then one bindings in basicHttpBinding element and leave out the services/service/endpoint/@bindingConfiguration attribute in the services section, it will work fine. However, in HTTPS, this will give you a 404. So remember to always add bindingConfiguration attribute to endpoints.